# Ansible not allowing environment at playbook level

Tags: ansible

I'm having issues defining environment variables at playbook level. [According to the docs it should be possible.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html)

```
$ ansible --version
1.7.1

$ ansible-playbook -i staging deploy.yml
ERROR: environment is not a legal parameter at this level in an Ansible Playbook
```

Here's the playbook simplified:

```
---
- hosts: app
  user: web

  environment:
    PATH: "{{ path_append }}:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"

  tasks:
    - ...
    - ...
```

Just to make sure, I tried setting it without the variables, and the result was equal.

Moving the environment-definition inside the tasks works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc was incorrect. It was a bug which was fixed in a later version (ansible 1.8). Can you upgrade to 1.9.x?

[Enable environment keyword at play level](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/8651)

Comment: Apparently 1.7.1 fetched by `apt-get` wasn't the newest version (not that I'm surprised). Should've done more research. Thanks!